# Using numba only for certain function in a larger NumPy project

Tags: fft, numba, jit

I am new to Numba and am trying to apply it to an existing NumPy code that is very FLOP intensive. The function I want to apply `@jit` to, however, calls other functions that, in turn, use the numpy fft module.

It seems that, in order to apply `@jit` to a function, it must also be applied to the functions it calls. As a consequence, I cannot apply `@jit` to my function - it would require applying it to all functions it calls and, ultimately, to the functions that use the fft module that is not supported by Numba. Is there a way around this? For instance, a way to let Numba know the data type of the variables returned by the functions called and instructing it to leave them alone? So that I can apply `@jit` only to the one function and not to those it calls?

Comment: What you can do is that instead of adding jit to the final function that consists of all other functions, add them to the functions that are compatible with Numba. Also, use Python built-in module and functions whenever possible as those are usually compatible with Numba.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to solve this problem is to split the functions in three parts: a header function using Numba, a pure-Python function (calling `np.fft`) and a footer Numba function. An overall pure-Python function coordinate the call to others. Using functions operating on big arrays is faster in this case due to the overhead of CPython loops.

That being said, there is an **experimental Numba feature called [`objmode`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/withobjmode.html?highlight=objmode#numba.objmode)** meant to solve this specific problem. You need to specify the type of the input/output objects of the section and there are few limitations mentioned in the documentation. Note that is currently quite unstable since I encountered few non-deterministic compilation errors (while the code was valid) and crashes while using it so far.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I decided against the "objmode" as it sounds buggy and should have a fairly heavy overhead if I understand the description correctly. Instead, I separated out the parts of the function that do not call (functions that call) np.fft functions - much like Jerome suggested. It feels like I butchered my code, but it gave a factor of 10-15 times speed-up right away! I also use the "prange" Numba function and, together with the @jit directive I now see up to 12 threads active during the computation.